# keras model not training while using half precision

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, precision, autoencoder

When I train my model using default precision in keras, the model gets trained. When I use the following code to convert it to half precision, I don't get similar results.

```
from keras import backend as K
import keras.backend as K
dtype='float16'
K.set_floatx(dtype)
```

When using the half precision, the validation loss never changes. I waited for 150 epochs but the validation loss was still the same. With the default precision, the model already converges before 150 epochs.

I am training it on images using autoencoder. I don't know if it's a common behavior. Can someone help?